# Does a basis of a directed-complete partial order contain all compact elements?

Tags: order-theory

I am currently reading an [introduction to domain theory](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~axj/pub/papers/handy.ps.gz). In the discussion of bases of dcpos it is stated that every basis contains the compact elements of said dcpo.

Both these notions depend on the notion of en element $x$ of a dcpo $(D, \sqsubseteq)$ approximating another element $y$, denoted $x \ll y$, meaning  for ever directed subset $A$ such that $y \in \; \downarrow \! \! \left(\bigsqcup \, A\right)$ one has $x \in \; \downarrow \!\! A$.

A compact element, now, means an element approximates itself. Denoting the set of elements approximating some element $x$ by $\downdownarrows \!\! x$ one defines a basis as a subset $B$ of $D$ such that every $B_x = \; \downdownarrows \!\! x \cap B$ is directed and with supremum $x$.

The proof given in the text states that that for some compact element $c \in D$:

> $\ldots$ since $c = \bigsqcup B_c$ there must be an element $b \in B_c$ above $c$.

Perhaps I am missing something obvious, but I cannot see why this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $c = \bigsqcup B_c$, so $c \ll c \in \downarrow \bigsqcup B_c$, and by definition of *approximates*, $c \in \downarrow B_c$, and hence there must be some $b \in B_c$ such that $c \le b$.

Comment: Doh! You are quite right, thank you for clearing it up!